# shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape while plotting bar plot

Tags: numpy, data-science, bar-chart, data-preprocessing

I am trying to bar plot for y_train and y_test data, But i am getting value mismatch error. Can someone help me fix it.

```
#Read the dataset - Amazon fine food reviews
reviews = pd.read_csv(r"Reviews.csv")
#get only 2 columns - Text, Score
#drop the NAN values
reviews = reviews[['Text', 'Score']]
reviews.head()
reviews = reviews.dropna()
reviews.drop(reviews[reviews['Score'] == 3].index, inplace = True)
reviews.loc[reviews['Score'] <= 2, 'Score'] = 0
reviews.loc[reviews['Score'] > 3, 'Score'] = 1
reviews
#remove HTML from the Text column and save in the Text column only
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#reviews['Text'] = reviews['Text'].str.replace(r'<[^<>]*>', '', regex=True)
reviews['Text'] = [BeautifulSoup(Text,"lxml").get_text() for Text in reviews['Text'] ]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(reviews['Text'],reviews['Score'] , test_size=0.20,stratify=reviews['Score'],random_state=33)
```

checking the shape of split of data

```
print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape, y_test.shape)

(80000,) (80000,)
(20000,) (20000,)
```

#plot bar graphs of y_train and y_test

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
plt.bar(y_train), y_test), color ='maroon')
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-6ec38d3b391c> in <module>()
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
----> 4 plt.bar(np.array(y_train), np.array(y_test), color ='maroon')
      5 

4 frames
<__array_function__ internals> in broadcast_arrays(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py in _broadcast_shape(*args)
    418     # use the old-iterator because np.nditer does not handle size 0 arrays
    419     # consistently
--> 420     b = np.broadcast(*args[:32])
    421     # unfortunately, it cannot handle 32 or more arguments directly
    422     for pos in range(32, len(args), 31):

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Comment: Doesn't your `shape` print tell you the problem.  One array is (8000,) and the other (2000,)!

Comment: Yes, I have got that. But i have done everything right in the code. But i am unable to figure out where i am going wrong

Comment: It makes more sense to plot `X_test`  against `y_test`, not the larger `train` against the `test`.  But I don't know what you are trying to do, or why you think you can plot a large array against a smaller one.

Comment: Its an assignment. I am doing text_classification using BERT. I have pre_processed the data as its asked in an assignment. But they have asked to to  plot bar graphs of y_train and y_test.